# Проблема с коэффициентом корреляции - pd.corr()

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Пытаюсь посчитать коэф. корреляции для каждой пары столбцов в DataFrame.

```
data = pd.read_csv('data.txt', sep="    ", index_col="Id")
print(data)

     505    506    507
   \
Id                                                                           
0    NaN    NaN    NaN   
1   37.2  107.0   69.0   
2    NaN  130.0   72.0  



for i in range(0, 3):
    for j in range(0, 3):
        if(j > i):
            a = data[data.columns[i:i+1]]
            b = data[data.columns[j:j+1]]

            r = a.corr(b)
```

Появляется ошибка.

---

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-31-d85ca44785ee> in <module>()
      5             b = data[data.columns[j:j+1]]
      6 
----> 7             r = a.corr(b)

~\Anaconda3\envs\ML\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in corr(self, method, min_periods)
   5487         mat = numeric_df.values
   5488 
-> 5489         if method == 'pearson':
   5490             correl = libalgos.nancorr(_ensure_float64(mat), minp=min_periods)
   5491         elif method == 'spearman':

~\Anaconda3\envs\ML\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in __nonzero__(self)
   1119         raise ValueError("The truth value of a {0} is ambiguous. "
   1120                          "Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."
-> 1121                          .format(self.__class__.__name__))
   1122 
   1123     __bool__ = __nonzero__

ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Comment: А какой стек трассы? А то непонятно на какой строке ошибка. Предполагаю что на `a = data[data.columns[i:i+1]]` или `r = a.corr(b)`

Comment: Исправил. Спасибо за замечание!

Comment: Попробуйте просто data.corr() без циклов...

Comment: Попробовал. Изменений нет, такая же ошибка.
`a = df[df.columns[0:1]]
b = df[df.columns[1:2]]

r = a.corr(b)`

Comment: @AndreyStebenkov, я привел пример в ответе...

Answer (score 1):

```
In [62]: data
Out[62]:
     505    506   507
Id
0    NaN    NaN   NaN
1   37.2  107.0  69.0
2    NaN  130.0  72.0

In [63]: data.corr()
Out[63]:
     505  506  507
505  NaN  NaN  NaN
506  NaN  1.0  1.0
507  NaN  1.0  1.0
```

---

вот пример с более правдоподобными данными:

```
In [85]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10,5), columns=list('abcde'))

In [86]: df.iloc[::3, [1,4]] = np.nan

In [87]: df.iloc[1::4, [2,3]] = np.nan

In [88]: df
Out[88]:
          a         b         c         d         e
0  0.292516       NaN  0.488364  0.235351       NaN
1  0.150342  0.497728       NaN       NaN  0.498478
2  0.936061  0.533680  0.488616  0.069263  0.306257
3  0.728724       NaN  0.841414  0.026519       NaN
4  0.970898  0.531654  0.508176  0.890823  0.608585
5  0.748113  0.662562       NaN       NaN  0.877368
6  0.900048       NaN  0.781662  0.799514       NaN
7  0.067932  0.074228  0.678235  0.476592  0.453969
8  0.426238  0.986512  0.865430  0.139393  0.352072
9  0.440932       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN

In [89]: df.corr()
Out[89]:
          a         b         c         d         e
a  1.000000  0.353552 -0.130399  0.265960  0.213295
b  0.353552  1.000000  0.431961 -0.367241  0.004186
c -0.130399  0.431961  1.000000 -0.167799 -0.304030
d  0.265960 -0.367241 -0.167799  1.000000  0.997583
e  0.213295  0.004186 -0.304030  0.997583  1.000000
```